# how to compile glog using mingw on linux to generate glog dlls

Tags: c++, linux, mingw, glog

I want to generate glog c++ dlls for windows using mingw on linux without using cmake or visual studio. Can anybody tell me the steps for doing so...Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Why?* Why don't you want to use the officially supplied build system? What is the actual problem you try to solve? And have you tried what [the `README` file](https://github.com/google/glog/blob/master/README) tells you?

Comment: Because I don't have visual studio installed on my windows system to make use of cmake. Basically i want to use glog on windows without using cmake or visual studio. So i thought of using mingw on linux to generate glog dll and create a exe in linux, which can be run on windows. Am I missing something, or i am thinking in wrong way. By the way, glog works excellently in my linux system. But i want the same to work on windows also....

Comment: You can [generate](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) a [MinGW Makefile](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/MinGW%20Makefiles.html) as well.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your help. I will work on it.

Comment: I get the following error. May I know, what to do now.
D:\glog-0.3.5\build>cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles"
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modu
    "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe"
  is not able to compile a simple test program.
  It fails with the following output:
    Change Dir: D:/glog-0.3.5/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp    Run Build Command:"C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_5628f/fast"
    C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../libmingwex.a(glob.o):(.text+0x8b8): undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't able to compile glog using MinGW. So I have compiled it using CMake & Visual Studio and the issue is resolved.